# Autenticação com o google no firebase retorna CANCELED

Tags: android, firebase, google

Tenho procurado a causa desse problema e já testei várias maneiras que vi aqui no Stack Overflowe mas nada parece resolver o problema.

Basicamente, estou tentando fazer a autenticaçao pela google e,quando chego à página de seleção da conta do Google e ela retorna à minha activity, sempre vejo um resultado de RESULT_CANCELED (ou seja, 0) em vez de RESULT_OK (ou seja, -1), independentemente da conta selecionada.

Verifiquei se as credenciais estão configuradas corretamente no google console e se as caves SHA-1(debug e release) foram adicionadas corretamente. Já até deletei meu projeto no firebase e criei um novo seguindo o passo a passo mas nada resolveu.

A minha chamada para autenticação:

```
 GoogleSignInOptions googleSignInOptions = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.client_id_google))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(LoginActivity.this, googleSignInOptions);
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
```

E a ActivityResultLauncher que espera o resultado:

```
   mStartForResult = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            result -> {
                if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    getInformationSignedAccountGoogle(result.getData());
                }
            });
```

Provavelmente é algo simples mas não consigo enxergar.